# Error message - A value of type 'Color?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color' because 'Color?' is nullable and 'Color' isn't

Tags: flutter

How do I resolve this issue because it worked in an older version of flutter saw it on a Youtube video dated 2 years ago. Added some constraints because it's required now.
Getting this error msg - A value of type 'Color?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color' because 'Color?' is nullable and 'Color' isn't.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'info.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: const MyPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
  }

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Restaurant"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            Hero(
              tag: "cakeitem",
              child: FittedBox(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InfoPage()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    // color: Colors.red,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        itemcake(),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 90,
                          height: 100,
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                            child: const Image(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              image: AssetImage('assets/cake.jpg'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FittedBox(
              child: Card(
                // color: Colors.red,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    juiceitem(),
                    Container(
                      width: 90,
                      height: 100,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        child: const Image(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          image: AssetImage('assets/juice.jpg'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FittedBox(
              child: Card(
                // color: Colors.red,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    pizzaitem(),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 90,
                      height: 100,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        child: const Image(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          image: AssetImage('assets/pizza.jpg'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FittedBox(
              child: Card(
                // color: Colors.red,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    eliteitem(),
                    Container(
                      width: 90,
                      height: 100,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        child: const Image(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          image: AssetImage('assets/elite.jpg'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget itemcake() {
    return Column(
      //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
          child: Text(
            "Italian Choco Cake",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        const Text(
          "Dark belgium chocolate",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              fontSize: 9.5,
              color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            const Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
              size: 15,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 35,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightBlue[100],
                //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                "Cold",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 9.5),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 35,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red[100],
                //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                "Fresh",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 9.5),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Ratings",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: 7,
                  color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget juiceitem() {
    return Container(
      //width: 150,
      child: Column(
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
            child: Text(
              "Fresh Mango Juice",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15, color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          const Text(
            "Dark belgium chocolate",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                fontSize: 9.5,
                color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
                size: 15,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 35,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.lightBlue[100],
                  //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text(
                  "Cold",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 9.5),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 35,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red[100],
                  //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text(
                  "Fresh",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 9.5),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 35,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.yellow[400],
                  //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text(
                  "New",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 9.5),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Ratings",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 7,
                    color: Colors.grey),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.star,
                size: 10,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.star,
                size: 10,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.star,
                size: 10,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.star,
                size: 10,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.star,
                size: 10,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget pizzaitem() {
    return Column(
      //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
          child: Text(
            "Cheese Pizza Italy ",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        const Text(
          "Double cheese New York Style",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              fontSize: 9.5,
              color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            const Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
              size: 15,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 35,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.deepOrange[300],
                //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                "Spicy",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 9.5),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 35,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.yellow[400],
                //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                "New",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 9.5),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Ratings",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: 7,
                  color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget eliteitem() {
    return Column(
      //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
          child: Text(
            "Alinea Chicago",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        const Text(
          "Classical French cooking",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              fontSize: 9.5,
              color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            const Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
              size: 15,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 35,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.deepOrange[300],
                //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                "Spicy",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 9.5),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 35,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                "Hot",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 9.5,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 35,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.yellow[400],
                //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                "New",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 9.5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Ratings",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: 7,
                  color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you indicated at which line the error occurred rather than us guessing. However, somewhere in there Color can be null. So when you assign it to something you have to tell Dart that it is not null. The way you do that is to use the bang character '!'.   Read up on Dart null safety.

Comment: Is that the Theme.of(context) which are nullable? If tes, you need to make sure that your thème is correctly est, with not nullable values, and use Theme.of(context).accentColor!. Also make sure to be up to date and to learn null safety for Dart

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn’t that one is nullable and the other is not. The problem is that one may have no value but the other requires one. So what do you think should happen if there is no value? You need to figure that out first before you can change your code.